# How to set Positive / Negative Button in DialogFragment?

Tags: android, button, dialog, android-dialogfragment

The solution was the onCreatDialog.
The other issue about crashed was caused by a LinearLayout parent in my listView xml

Here my code [EDITED]:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null);
        ListView mListView = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.lvListe);

        String[] mValues = {"Orientation", "Nombre de Chambres", "Nombre de Salle de bains", "Nombre de toilettes", "Cave", "Parking", "Garage", "Jardin"};

        getDialog().setTitle("Autres Critères");

        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mValues));

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setPositiveButton("ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                onCancel(dialog);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .create();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are onCreateDialog then no need to write the onCreateView, create your dialog inside onCreateDialog and set the button actions there.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the `createDialog()` method of `DialogFragment`.

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      // DO SOMETHING
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // DO SOMETHING
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}
```

Comment: With this approach you will loose  the custom view

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `AlertDialog.Builder` like such:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    Bundle args = getArguments();

    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setMessage(args.getString(ARG_MESSAGE));
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do stuff here
        }
    });
    //cancel button with dismiss.
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             dismiss();
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Now my onCreatView makes me crash :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (or in addition to) implementing onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) to generate the view hierarchy inside of a dialog, you may implement onCreateDialog(Bundle) to create your own custom Dialog object.

This is most useful for creating an AlertDialog, allowing you to display standard alerts to the user that are managed by a fragment. A simple example implementation of this is:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}
```

}

Comment: Now my onCreatView makes me crash :/